# Web application to view database information

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to view database information via a web application. Since I don't want to install mysql client on my machine.

Comment: What type of database information you would like to show?

Comment: May be you are looking for phpmysqladmin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Via a web application, you can install  [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/).

Otherwise, if you can install something on your machine there are tools that work for any DB, like [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/) or the MySQL specific MySQL Query Browser part of [MySQL GUI Tools](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html).